# Does DocumentsContract.deleteDocument cancel takePersistableUriPermission?

Tags: android, delete-file, storage-access-framework

In my app the user can create a backup, with the following workflow:

- user selects a destination (opening SAF UI and selecting a destination)
- user chooses some options
- user either presses a start button to create the backup, or cancels and goes back

I'm trying to do this with Storage Access Framework (since with Android 10 we are forced to use that... thing). I'm using an ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT intent. When doing so, Android creates an empty file as soon as the user picks a destination.

If the app crashes / is killed, or if the user goes back, the empty file will still be there (in case of the user going back of course I can delete it in onDestroy, but that will not work if there's a crash / kill).

To reduce the risk of having that empty file, I'd like to delete it in onActivityResult, and create it only if the user effectively creates the backup.

To do so, in onActivityResult I call `takePersistableUriPermission`, and then `DocumentsContract.deleteDocument`. But then when trying to create the file the app crashes:

```
Permission Denial: writing com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider uri [...] from pid=9543, uid=10136 requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS, or grantUriPermission()
```

It works if I do not call `DocumentsContract.deleteDocument`, so my writing code seems correct (I'm using `getContentResolver().openOutputStream`).

So, the question is: is it crashing because calling `DocumentsContract.deleteDocument` revoked my write permission, even though I called `takePersistableUriPermission`??

If so, is there any way to delete the file while keeping the write permission? `android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` is reserved to system apps, but is there a way with `grantUriPermission()`?

Even better, is there a way to prevent SAF to create a dummy empty file??

Comment: If the user creates an empty file onActivityResult is invoked where you can write to the file to make a backup. You are suggesting that the user can create a backup outside onActivityResult. Further i do not understand that you wanna delete the new file.  You should use it to backup. Please explain yourself better.

Comment: An empty file will not get created if the user goes back. Please ecplain.

Comment: My experience is that deleting a file deletes the permission too.

Comment: The backup creation is indeed not started in onActivityResult, but after the user has pressed a "Start" button. So I'm saving the Uri in onActivityResult, and I'm using it when the start button is pressed.

Comment: SAF does creates an empty file only if the user presses the Save button. After that onActivityResult is triggered where you can write to the file. I dont see any problem as SAF does not create dummy empty files.

Comment: `Android creates an empty file as soon as the user picks a destination.`. No. Only after a file name is typed in and the Save button pressed.

Comment: `the question is: is it crashing because ....` Your app does not have to crash if you catch the exception.

Comment: `with the following workflow:

user selects a destination` No. The user creates an empty file in s certain destination.

Comment: User cancels after the options or later. Yes then you have an empty file. Conclusion: wrong work flow. Do the file creation last.

Comment: Who determines the filename of the backup?

Comment: But i would once let the user choose a directory with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. After that you can create at any time as much files in that directory as you want.

Comment: "No. Only after a file name is typed in and the Save button pressed" -> that's what I meant by "the user picks a destination".

Comment: "Your app does not have to crash if you catch the exception" -> Funny. The problem is not the crash, it is the permission being revoked.

Comment: "wrong work flow. Do the file creation last." -> SAF is a framework. A framework is supposed the help devs to create softwares, not to force them to use an ugly design. Starting the backup creation (which may take a while) right after showing the SAF UI would be very confusing for the user.

Comment: "Who determines the filename of the backup?" -> I give SAF the file name, but the user can change it (another SAF flaw: there's no way to force the file extension. If you try to save a "test.jpg" file, the user can rename it "test.pdf" >< . But that's another story).

Comment: "But i would once let the user choose a directory with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE" -> This would be ugly as well. I don't want to be granted a write access to a whole directory tree, I want to select a destination a write to it afterwards. Seems SAF doesn't handle that totally exotic workflow...